# how to do design like stepper in flutter like below image?

Tags: flutter

i want to do design shown in image. when click on '+' button status should updated.

for example if i click on '+' button 'Heat,natural' and date should updated and '+' button should move downwards.

then again click on '+' button INSEMINATION and date should update and goes on.

i don't want stepper. i need to do with any widgets. please help me. thank you in advance

[image: if i click on '+' button 'Heat,natural' and date should updated and '+' button should move downwards]

Comment: Have you realized this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using listvew.
Use list view without any margin and padding to join the vertical line.
U
You can use vertical devicer or simply a container with 1px width for vertical lines.
Manage wisely the layout the joining the vertical lines.
Happy fluttering.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://pub.dev/packages/timeline_list

```
import 'package:timeline_list/timeline.dart';
import 'package:timeline_list/timeline_model.dart';

List<TimelineModel> items = [
      TimelineModel(Placeholder(),
          position: TimelineItemPosition.random,
          iconBackground: Colors.redAccent,
          icon: Icon(Icons.blur_circular)),
      TimelineModel(Placeholder(),
          position: TimelineItemPosition.random,
          iconBackground: Colors.redAccent,
          icon: Icon(Icons.blur_circular)),
    ];
    return Timeline(children: items, position: TimelinePosition.Center);
```

Comment: when activity starts only first timeline should be there. click on first timeline second timeline should be added dynamically. thank you for reply